# scale_fill_manual factor levels, colours, or order ignored

Tags: r, ggplot2, terra

I am having difficulty creating a map with `scale_fill_manual` to fill regions on the map based on some property in the region. I am using `tidyterra` with `terra` and the `tidyverse` packages. I am unaware of methods for writing self-contained map files in r, so I provide a link to download a map file that is suitable for demonstrating the issue I am having (from [Birds Canada](https://www.birdscanada.org/bird-science/nabci-bird-conservation-regions)).

The problem appears as though the factor levels were unordered or ordered incorrectly. Similar to these posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50647122/ggplot-not-respectig-order-of-colours-in-scale-fill-manual) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45247428/factor-levels-and-scale-fill-manual-arguments-ignored-in-ggplot-r). However, I am explicitly naming factors created by `cut`, which has an argument to order the factor output. Here is a link to [download the 24 MB zip file](https://birdscanada.org/download/gislab/bcr_terrestrial_shape.zip) with the map.

```
library(terra)
library(tidyterra)
library(tidyverse)

map_file <- vect("~/Downloads/BCR_Terrestrial/BCR_Terrestrial_master.shp") %>%
  project("+proj=lcc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-95 +lat_1=49 +lat_2=77 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs") %>% 
  subset(., !(.$OBJECTID %in% c(1, 354, 371, 372)) & .$COUNTRY != "MEXICO")

set.seed(123)

properties <- tibble(
  Mean = rnorm(9, mean = 0, sd = 0.25),
  BCR = rep(c(6,11,17),3),
  Process = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)) %>% 
  mutate(
    Mu = cut(Mean, breaks = c(-Inf, -0.4, -0.3, -0.2, -0.1, -0.05, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, Inf),
             labels = c("< 0.4", "-0.4 : -0.3", "-0.3 : -0.2", "-0.2 : -0.1", "-0.1 : -0.05", "-0.05 : 0.05",
                        "0.05 : 0.1", "0.1 : 0.2", "0.2 : 0.3", "0.3 : 0.4", "> 0.4"),
             ordered_result = T))

sp_map <- merge(subset(map_file, map_file$BCR %in% properties[["BCR"]]), properties)

ggplot(sp_map)+
  geom_spatvector(aes(fill = Mu))+
  facet_wrap(~Process)+
  geom_spatvector(data = subset(map_file, !map_file$BCR %in% sp_map$BCR), fill = "white", size = 0.1)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#a50026",
                               "#d73027",
                               "#f46d43",
                               "#fdae61",
                               "#fee090",
                               "#ffffbf",
                               "#e0f3f8",
                               "#abd9e9",
                               "#74add1",
                               "#4575b4",
                               "#313695"),
                    name = "Spice", drop = F)+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.title = element_blank())
```

Running this code, you will see that the colours in the map legend are ordered correctly but the factor levels themselves are not. Also, the `drop = F` argument is ignored (not every level of the factor is in the legend).
[image: Factors are not ordered correctly]

Alternatively, if I name the `values` vector argument like this:

```
ggplot(sp_map)+
  geom_spatvector(aes(fill = Mu))+
  facet_wrap(~Process)+
  geom_spatvector(data = subset(map_file, !map_file$BCR %in% sp_map$BCR), fill = "white", size = 0.1)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("< 0.4"="#a50026",
                               "-0.4 : -0.3"="#d73027",
                               "-0.3 : -0.2"="#f46d43",
                               "-0.2 : -0.1"="#fdae61",
                               "-0.1 : -0.05"="#fee090",
                               "-0.05 : 0.05"="#ffffbf",
                               "0.05 : 0.1"="#e0f3f8",
                               "0.1 : 0.2"="#abd9e9",
                               "0.2 : 0.3"="#74add1",
                               "0.3 : 0.4"="#4575b4",
                               "> 0.4"="#313695"),
                    name = "Spice", drop = F)+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.title = element_blank())
```

[image: Colours match but order is wrong in legend. Not all factor levels present]

The order of the colours is respected among factor levels but not in the legend. Furthermore, still not all levels are represented in the legend. I am stumped. The two attempts here are my most salient efforts but I have tried reordering in another `factor` call, remove labels, changing labels, so on...

Any guidance here would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I think it would be perfectly possible to create a reproducible example that didn't involve downloading a 24MB data file.

Comment: Yes, I realize this is an inconvenience. The shapefile itself is only 13 mb, but the publisher bundles it with other supplementary files. Regrettably, I am not sure how to more conveniently provide access to this file. Still, it should only take a moment or two to download and unzip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity, I'll post the answer to resolve the two issues that arose in my code.

In brief, although the factor levels were defined and ordered in the data object, it seems like the `spatvector` map object converted all the factors back into characters. To fix this, I converted the argument to `fill` back into a factor in place in the ggplot call. This allowed the `drop=F` argument and the order to be respected.

```
ggplot(sp_map)+
  geom_spatvector(aes(fill = factor(Mu, levels = c("< 0.4", "-0.4 : -0.3", "-0.3 : -0.2", "-0.2 : -0.1", "-0.1 : -0.05", "-0.05 : 0.05",
                                                   "0.05 : 0.1", "0.1 : 0.2", "0.2 : 0.3", "0.3 : 0.4", "> 0.4"))))+
  facet_wrap(~Process)+
  geom_spatvector(data = subset(map_file, !map_file$BCR %in% sp_map$BCR), fill = "white", size = 0.1)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("< 0.4"="#a50026",
                               "-0.4 : -0.3"="#d73027",
                               "-0.3 : -0.2"="#f46d43",
                               "-0.2 : -0.1"="#fdae61",
                               "-0.1 : -0.05"="#fee090",
                               "-0.05 : 0.05"="#ffffbf",
                               "0.05 : 0.1"="#e0f3f8",
                               "0.1 : 0.2"="#abd9e9",
                               "0.2 : 0.3"="#74add1",
                               "0.3 : 0.4"="#4575b4",
                               "> 0.4"="#313695"),
                    name = "Spice", drop = F)+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.title = element_blank())
```

Generates:

[image]

I don't know why the spatvector has this behaviour, whether I am misusing the package or made some error somewhere. In any event, hopefully this is useful someone else down the road!